# Sort table by Alphanumeric column in Postgres

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql, sorting

So far, I've come up with

```
ORDER BY SUBSTRING(COLUMN FROM '[A-Z]+'), COALESCE(SUBSTRING(COLUMN FROM '(?<=-)[0-9]+')::INTEGER, 0), SUBSTRING(COLUMN FROM '(?<=\()[0-9]+')::BIGINT
```

| Outcome | Desired Outcome |
| --- | --- |
| AC-1 | AC-1 |
| AC-2 (1) | **AC-2** |
| AC-2 (2) | AC-2 (1) |
| **AC-2** | AC-2 (2) |
| AC-3 (1) | AC-3 (1) |
| AC-3 (2) | AC-3 (2) |
| AC-3 (3) | AC-3 (3) |

Comment: I don't get your point. Why to bother to use Regex? Won't "ORDER BY" alone work?

Comment: No, That won't work. It would give:  AC-1, AC-10, AC-11 ... AC-2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As with most SQL engines, the default behavior of postgresql when comparing NULLs to other values is to put NULLs last, so when the optional number preceded by a left parenthesis fails to match and becomes NULL, it gets placed last.

You can change the behavior to put NULLs first with the `NULLS FIRST` option:

```
ORDER BY
  SUBSTRING(COLUMN FROM '[A-Z]+'),
  COALESCE(SUBSTRING(COLUMN FROM '(?<=-)[0-9]+')::INTEGER, 0),
  SUBSTRING(COLUMN FROM '(?<=\()[0-9]+')::BIGINT NULLS FIRST
```

Comment: Well, That was nice :) +1.

Answer (score 2):

That is simple: just define the appropriate collation.

```
CREATE COLLATION mycoll (
   PROVIDER = icu,
   LOCALE = 'und-u-kn-true'
);

SELECT col FROM tab ORDER BY col COLLATE mycoll;
```

With old versions of the ICU library, you might have to define the `LOCALE` as `@colNumeric=true`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I can't make changes to the db. This answer will help users who can.

Comment: Then the solution is even simpler: just tell the people who can make the change to create the collation. It is not like creating a collation will endanger your database.

Answer (score 1):

Using your current data; I created [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/80b38/7).

The following query shall work for you :

```
SELECT my_column
FROM mytable
ORDER BY 
  SUBSTRING(my_column FROM '[A-Z]+') ASC, 
  COALESCE(SUBSTRING(my_column FROM '(?<=-)[0-9]+')::INTEGER, 0) ASC,
  CASE WHEN my_column ~ '^([A-Z]+-[0-9]+)$' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END DESC,
  SUBSTRING(my_column FROM '\([0-9]+\)*$') ASC;
```

It gives me desired output as :

```
my_column
AC-1
AC-2
AC-2 (1)
AC-2 (2)
AC-3 (1)
AC-3 (2)
AC-3 (3)
```

Please replace `my_column` with your actual `column_name` and `mytable` with actual `table_name`

Comment: Thanks for the efforts, the other answer is simpler so accepted it as the answer.

Comment: Yup,
Obviously. and I am glad that you accepted that answer